# Botframework V4: Question about Input forms cards

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

Hello i have this input forms card. It is rendering properly but how can i get its results? And how can i make it so that the bot wait for the user to submit before proceding to the next step? Putting stepContext.NextAsync will automatically trigger the next step. But removing it will cause an error because it needs to return something.

```
   public InitialQuestions(string dialogId, IEnumerable<WaterfallStep> steps = null)
        : base(dialogId, steps)
    {
        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var cardAttachment = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(_cards);
            var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment };
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);

            // how can i wait for user to click submit before going to next step?
            return await stepContext.NextAsync();

            // return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
            //   "textPrompt",
            //   new PromptOptions
            //   {
            //       Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(""),
            //   },
            //   cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            // next step
        });
    }

     private static Attachment CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(string filePath)
    {
        var adaptiveCardJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCardJson),
        };
        return adaptiveCardAttachment;
    }
```

This is the card

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "What is your Occupation?"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "Occupation",
      "placeholder": "Occupation"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Are you married? "
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "id": "Married",
      "value": "true",
      "choices": [
        {
          "title": "Yes",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "title": "No",
          "value": "false"
        }
      ],
      "style": "expanded"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "When is your birthday?"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Date",
      "id": "Birthday",
      "value": ""
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit",
      "data": {
        "id": "1234567890"
      }
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Thanks guys.

EDIT: for future reference of others this is the answer i found.

```
    AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        var state = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["BasicAccessors"] as BasicAccessors).BasicStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);

        var jsonString = (JObject)stepContext.Context.Activity.Value;
        BasicState results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BasicState>(jsonString.ToString());
        state.Occupation = results.Occupation;
        state.Married = results.Married;
        state.Birthday = results.Birthday;

        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your questions in reverse order:

> And how can i make it so that the bot wait for the user to submit before proceding to the next step? Putting stepContext.NextAsync will automatically trigger the next step. But removing it will cause an error because it needs to return something.

Yes, it's true, you need to return something from your step, but as you point out you're not ready for it to move to the next step yet. The answer is that you want to use a prompt at this point! Now I see you have some code in here commented out to do this and maybe what's confusing is that, today, there is no specific prompt for working with cards. Instead you do want to use a general purpose `TextPrompt` and we'll set the activity on that to something other than just simple text.

With this in mind, you would keep your code above that is using `CreateReply` to build your `Activity` with card attachments, but, instead of sending that `Activity` yourself with `SendActivityAsync` you want to set it as the value of the `Prompt` property of the `TextPrompt` like so:

```cs
AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
               "myPrompt",
               new PromptOptions
               {
                   Prompt = new Activity 
                   {
                       Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
                       Attachments = new List<Attachment>() 
                       { 
                          CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(_cards),
                       },
                   },
               },
               cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

        });
```

Ok, so that's one half of the problem. With that in mind now, let's circle back to the first part of your question:

> Hello i have this input forms card. It is rendering properly but how can i get its results?

Well, your adaptive card is using the `Submit` action which means that you will receive an activity that contains the values of the form in the `Values` property of the `Activity`, however because we used a `TextPrompt` above the default validation behavior of the `TextPrompt` is going to be validating that some value was supplied for the `Text` portion of the `Activity` which there won't be in this case. So, to fix that, when you configure the `TextPrompt` you really want to provide your own `PromptValidator<T>` like so:

```cs
    Add(new TextPrompt("myPrompt", new PromptValidator<string>(async (pvc, ct) => true)));
```

This basically says the input is valid no matter what. You could make it richer if you wanted by actually checking the details of the value, but this should unblock you for now.

Now, back in your `WaterfallDialog` your next step is going to be receiving the `Activity` whose `Value` property will be a `JObject` which you can either use directly or you can call `JObject::ToObject<T>` to convert it into a specific class you've created that represents your form input:

```cs
AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
           // This will give you a JObject representation of the incoming values 
           var rawValues = (JObject)stepContext.Context.Activity.Values;

           // You can convert that to something more strongly typed like so
           // where MyFormValues is a class you've defined
           var myFormValues = rawValues.ToObject<MyFormValues>();
        });
```

I want to just close this answer out by saying that, in answering your question, I've recorded a bunch of feedback that I intend to send to the product team to improve this situation both in terms of API design and documentation because, clearly, this is not obvious or optimal.

Comment: Sir i'm getting an error in "ToObject" is there a nuget package needed for that? I have a class "BasicState" with properties named "Occupation,Birthday,Married".

Comment: Sorry, I left a cast to `JObject` out of my answer's code, updating now.

Comment: Thank you sir sorry this is my first time working with json. And can you teach me too how to access those json values directly?

Comment: Well the short answer is you can use it like a dictionary to access each value you need, but I promise if you search this site there are plenty of questions/answers around how to use `JObject`.

Comment: I edited my question with the answer sir drew. Is my answer okay or save for concurrent users?

Comment: This is a ton of additional overhead because you're going back to a string just to parse it as JSON all over again: `BasicState results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BasicState>(jsonString.ToString());`. You already have a `JObject`, so you should just call it's `.ToObject<BasicState>`. Much less code, much less garbage created, much better performance.  As for safe for concurrent users, as long as your `BasicAccessors` accessor is associated with `ConversationState` or `UserState` you should be good to go. 

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Here is another questio from me about dialogs sir drew. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397081/botframework-v4-dialogs